# ios sdk error: framework not found FrontBoardServices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ionic3

I don't know why IOS try to use this framework, when I delete it and try to build the projet .. it still complains saying that can't find some framework.

This happens with FrontBoardService.framework and WebCore.framework

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2IOV.png)

[framework list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhRpU.png)

Comment: Try clean and buildign the project. Or clean the build folder and try restarting Xcode. It could also be possible that when you deleted and re added the frameworks, it might have messed up some settings or symbolic links.

Comment: This framework doesnt exists on sdk(thats why Xcode dont find him) .. I alred try to clean and restart Xcode and the error remains.